# add a bigger arrayList to a smaller arrayList in java

Tags: java, collections

I have a problem and no idea how to start, please help.

I got two ArrayList one is smaler and the other one is bigger, and now I have to add the values from the bigger to the smaller list but maintained all the values from both the lists

For example, We have two arrayLists

```
  ArrayList1[1,2,3]
  ArrayList2[3,5,7,5]

  ArrayListResult[4,7,10,5]
```

Comment: @J.Lucky it's number addition, 1+3=4, 2+5=7 ...

Comment: @AeOn have you tried something?

Comment: I see it the following way: you get the largest List(simple comparison) and then in a loop you start summing 2 values and adding it to a new list, you have to check if your loop heats the length of smaller ArrayList you should just start adding elemnts to new arraylist from the old long one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
int l1 = ArrayList1.size(); int l2 = ArrayList2.size();
int max = Math.max(l1, l2);
ArrayList<Integer> ArrayListResult = new ArrayList<Integer>(max);


for (int i = 0; i<max; i++ ) {

    ArrayListResult.set(i,0);
    if(i < l1) {
         ArrayListResult.set(i,ArrayList1.get(i)+ArrayListResult.get(i));
    }
    if(i < l2) {
         ArrayListResult.set(i,ArrayList2.get(i)+ArrayListResult.get(i));
    }
}
```

*Might be a more elegant solution than having 2 tests in the loop but that should work.*

Answer (score 2):

Just take elements from two iterators in parallel, while summing up the values, and building the new result array list.

When you finished with the shortest list, you simply run through the longer list's `iterator`, and append the values to the result list.

Something like this:

```
List<Integer> l1 = ...;  // shorter
List<Integer> l2 = ...;  // longer
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // result

Iterator<Integer> i1 = l1.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> i1 = l2.iterator();

// Add the numbers as long as both lists have elements at that position
while(i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
    result.append(i1.next() + i2.next());
}

// Append the remaining elements.
// Note that it's not possible for both lists to have remaining elements.
while(i1.hasNext()) {
    result.append(i1.next());
}
while(i2.hasNext()) {
    result.append(i2.next());
}
```

Comment: actually one iteration should be enough and using `get` `set` of the `List` interface.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have a check like this ..

Say my ArrayList A is [0,1,2] and B is [3,4,5,6]

I will check their size say if A size is less then i would add a zero at end ..

Then it will not throw me the exception and i can go on and add..

Try the below code :

```
List<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            A.add(i);
        }

        System.out.println("A list is below................");
        for (Integer a : A) {

            System.out.println(a);
        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= 6; i++) {
            B.add(i);
        }
        if(A.size()<B.size()){
            A.add(0);
        }
        System.out.println("B list is below................");
        for (Integer b : B) {

            System.out.println(b);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <=B.size()-1; i++) {
            result.add(A.get(i) + B.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("After Adding .................");
        for (Integer r : result) {

            System.out.println(r);
        }
```